# Add sprites created in Scene Editor to a programmatically created scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift3

I want to add some sprite nodes created in Scene Editor to a scene created programmatically. I tried doing this in the following manner:

```
class hudSKSScene: SKScene {
    var arrows: [SKSpriteNode: SKSpriteNode] = [SKSpriteNode: SKSpriteNode]() 

    // init and other functions here

    func setupArrows(scale: CGFloat) {
        let controllerScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "controllerScene.sks") // scene containing 8 sprites

        let arrowUp = controllerScene?.childNode(withName: "up") as! SKSpriteNode
        let arrowDown = controllerScene?.childNode(withName: "down") as! SKSpriteNode
        let arrowLeft = controllerScene?.childNode(withName: "left") as! SKSpriteNode
        let arrowRight = controllerScene?.childNode(withName: "right") as! SKSpriteNode

        let arrowUpPressed = controllerScene?.childNode(withName: "upPressed") as! SKSpriteNode
        let arrowDownPressed = controllerScene?.childNode(withName: "downPressed") as! SKSpriteNode
        let arrowLeftPressed = controllerScene?.childNode(withName: "leftPressed") as! SKSpriteNode
        let arrowRightPressed = controllerScene?.childNode(withName: "rightPressed") as! SKSpriteNode

        arrows[arrowUp] = arrowUpPressed
        arrows[arrowDown] = arrowDownPressed
        arrows[arrowLeft] = arrowLeftPressed
        arrows[arrowRight] = arrowRightPressed

        for (arrow, arrowPressed) in arrows {
            arrow.zPosition = 2
            arrowPressed.zPosition = 1
            addChild(arrowPressed)
            addChild(arrow)
        }
```

The scene is actually an overlay scene for a `SceneKit` based game. I want to add the controllers in the following manner because this way I can easily position them.

It seems I am causing an **exception** because I am adding the sprites to the scene, when they are already a child of the scene in which they are created (in `controllerScene.sks`). I am getting the following message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent: 
<SKSpriteNode> name:'leftPressed' texture:[<SKTexture> 'trianglePressed'
```

How should I be creating them and/or adding them to the scene?

Comment: why don't you just make your overlay in sprite kit editor, then save the sks file, and add it as an SKReferenceNode

Comment: but anyway, you need to use `moveToParent(SKNode)` or `removeFromParent()` before attaching to another parent